# Arduino I2C - data stream stopped unexpectedly

Tags: arduino, i2c, serial-communication

I am trying to connect an Arduino Uno to a temperature sensor using I2C. At first, the Arduino can send the data stream, but it stops a few minutes later...

If I restart the board, the Arduino can send the data stream, but again it stops a few minutes later. I wonder whether my code is wrong. Please help me.

```
/*
 Program akses DT-SENSE Temp SENSOR - Arduino
 Vizard Vision @ 2013 
*/
#include <Wire.h>
void setup() {
  Wire.begin();            
  Serial.begin(38400);     
}
int buffer = 0;
int count = 0;
void loop() {
  if(count >= 6000) {
    count = 0;
  }
  Wire.beginTransmission(112); // transmit to device #112 (0x70)
  // the address specified in the datasheet is 224 (0xE0) --> 1110 0000 = E0H
  // but i2c adressing uses the high 7 bits so it's 112 --> 0111 0000 = 70H
  Wire.send(0x00);
  // command sensor to measure 16 Byte of Temperature Data
  Wire.endTransmission();    
  delay(100);               

  Wire.requestFrom(112, 2);
  // request 2 bytes from slave device #112
  if(2 <= Wire.available()) {
    // if two bytes were received
    buffer = Wire.receive();
    // receive high byte (overwrites previous reading)
    buffer = buffer << 8;
    // shift high byte to be high 8 bits
    buffer |= Wire.receive();
    // receive low byte as lower 8 bits
    buffer = (buffer - 400)/10;
    // Conversion data to Temperature (from datasheet)
    Serial.print(count);
    Serial.print(" Suhu = ");
    Serial.print(buffer);
    Serial.write(176);
    // Unicode value of Degree Symbol
    Serial.println("Celsius");
    count ++;
    Serial.flush();
  }
  delay(40);
}
```

Comment: This looks very clean. You could put a delay in-between the Wire.requestFrom and the Wire.available() calls. It is strange that buffer and count are global. But if I had to guess I would say it is your baud of 38400 is to fast for your cable. Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a problem here:

```
  if(2 <= Wire.available())    // if two bytes were received
  {
    buffer = Wire.receive();  // receive high byte (overwrites previous reading)
    buffer = buffer << 8;    // shift high byte to be high 8 bits
    buffer |= Wire.receive(); // receive low byte as lower 8 bits
```

It will get into the block if there is 1 or 2 bytes available. If there is 2 bytes, it will go through both `Wire.receive()` and your `buffer` variable will be setup correctly, and you're happy. If there is only 1 byte, it will pass first `Wire.receive()`, and on second `Wire.receive()` you'll have an unexpected behaviour (*i.e.* documentation does not tell what it does when that happens). So I'd expect it to be blocking until a byte comes, but as it will never come, it blocks infinitely.

Then you'd wonder "*why would this ever return a single byte?*". And there can be many reasons:

- the datasheet may be lying and on very specific circumstances your i2c slave may return a single byte,
- your connection is mishandled at one point, and the slave writes both bytes at an incorrect speed making your lib believe it's only one byte,
- there's a false contact in your i2c line and under weird circumstances (temperature, pressure, vibration, a storm in Nicaragua) and only one of the two bytes are getting through the connection...

So you should do the following:

```
  if(Wire.available() == 2)    // if two bytes were received
  {
    buffer = Wire.receive();  // receive high byte (overwrites previous reading)
    buffer = buffer << 8;    // shift high byte to be high 8 bits
    buffer |= Wire.receive(); // receive low byte as lower 8 bits
```

which will make you avoid going through the unexpected behavior!